# Restore "snapshot" of OS partition on physical Linux server to spare partition then boot - caveats?

Tags: linux, snapshot

We're planning to bring a new physical server online in the near future and as part of the disaster recovery / change management plan, I want to be able to easily roll back the operating system and other software without affecting any data such as logs / user or website data / databases / etc.

I was thinking something like the following:

- 40 GB for OS/program partition
- 500 GB for data partition
- 40 GB unused for restoring OS/program if needed

Then if ever needing to roll back, we could just do an online bare metal restore to the unused partition (or proactively have restored to it before making changes that we're concerned about), and then edit the boot config to boot from it instead.

I'd plan to move /var/log, /var/lib/mysql, and user and website directories to reside on the data partition and also look through a filtered and aggregated output of `lsof` and recently-modified files to identify any other files that may need to reside there such as programs logging to other locations.

Does this seem like a good idea?  Are there any caveats or things to be aware of that I'm missing?

Comment: It depends.  Are you looking for an elegant solution, something turn-key or something that fits into your existing backup/BCP/DR solution?  My initial thought is that you'd want 2 spare partitions if you're concerned about versioning for updates; 1 spare is with the base OS, and 1 spare is the last good.

Comment: Doesn't need to be turn key - just making sure the concept is solid and then we can make it work.  I like your idea of having 2 spare.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do the follow:

- Create 1 partition for the primary system*
- Create 1 partition for the applications and home files (if necessary)
- Create 1 partition for a clean install of the primary system*
- Create 1 partition to use for a last known good*

Ideally, you should use separate physical drives for these.  I'd recommend SSD's for the items I've marked with '*' as they'd be more reliable and long lasting. You wouldn't have to worry about spinning disks freezing from no use or wasting space on a disk you're using for important stuff.  Worst case scenario is you just swap the OS drive and everything's good; unless you're hosting something on the server that is time/log sensitive, like email or databases.  If that's the case, then you'll want to invest in a 3rd party complete system restore application that'll restore translogs and such.

As for making a backup or a clean install, that's relatively easy.  Use `dd_rescue`.  It'll do a bit-by-bit copy of whatever you want to whatever you want.  Basically, use `dd_rescue` to make a duplicate of the OS partition(s) onto a separate drive after you've set it up and configured it the way you need, then store that second drive some place safe.  Then, every year/month/week or time interval of your choosing or before every major upgrade, use `dd_rescue` to make an effect snapshot of your OS partition(s) onto a spare drive.

Alternatively, you can invest in something like Unitrends or NetBackup to do bare-metal backups/restores; they'll have a SAN you can store all your backups on, then you can restore to physical or virtual systems however you see fit.

Comment: If I'm wanting to relocate the "time/log sensitive, like email or databases" stuff off the system disk, is there anything I might be missing or issues I might encounter that wouldn't be covered by my original question? Thanks

Comment: It depends on the applications.  You'll need to create a custom backup solution for each application or invest in a turn-key backup solution.  The process is made easier if you separate your OS into one partition and all other files into another partition; this way,  you can manage your backups in a more granular level.  Every application is unique.  Here's an example for how to backup sendmail http://goo.gl/uCs1vk and how to backup MySQL http://goo.gl/jFM4eq